# Using a regular expression (perl?) on a MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, perl, regular-expressions

I have a MYSQL DB and I need to do some text manipulation on one of the fields.  This is a one-off, not an ongoing process.

The built in MySQL text manipulation functions will be a nightmare to do what I need to do.
Perl can do it in a few lines, and I even have a perl script hanging aorund with the exact text manipulation commands needed.

Dumping the table to a text file, Perling it, and then restoring it would work but is a bit cumbersome; is there an easier or better way to use perl to manipulate the data within the mysql DB to cycle through each row in the table, edit the data in a field, and move on the the next row?

Answer (score 2):

The best method would be to modify the data "in place" using Perl's [MySQL DBI](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/dbi.html).

`SELECT` the data, perform the regex and send it back with an `UPDATE`.

My personal preference would be to use Python, with it's [MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) and [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) module with the [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::mysql) driver to access the database for reading and writing, and just loop through the rows you're interested in. The documentation should be enough to give you a decent start, but it could be a good idea to back things up before you break stuff.